# Simple for loop in Alexa Skill

Tags: python, for-loop, alexa-skills-kit

I'm creating a simple Alexa Skill in Python in which a list of random numbers is generated and told to the user. I don't know why if I use `for` or `while` loops the skill does not work. If I use, instead, a number spoken by a user, the skill correctly works. How can I generate a list of random numbers within my intent? Here is my code:

```
class RandomNumberIntentHandler(AbstractRequestHandler):
    """Handler for Hello World Intent."""
    def can_handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> bool
        return ask_utils.is_intent_name("RandomNumberIntent")(handler_input)

    def handle(self, handler_input):
        # type: (HandlerInput) -> Response
        slots = handler_input.request_envelope.request.intent.slots
        size = slots["size"].value
        n = slots["n"].value

        results = get_random_values(size,n)

        speak_output = "You got " + results.join(', ')


        return (
            handler_input.response_builder
                .speak(speak_output)
                # .ask("add a reprompt if you want to keep the session open for the user to respond")
                .response
        )

    def get_random_values(size,n):
        result = []
        for i in range(n):
            result.append(randint(1, size))
        return result
```

PS: I've already tried list comprhension and to put the generation directly within the intent but it does not work.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what you used in `get_random_values` but you can try using `random.sample(range(100), size)`

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected the code!

Comment: It still applies, let me know if `random.sample(...)` worked for you

Comment: It does not work!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this line

```
speak_output = "Hai ottenuto " + results.join(', ')
```

You can't join a list of integers in that way.

Try

```
speak_output = "Hai ottenuto " + ', '.join(map(str, results))
```

That is:

- mapping every integer of `results` to a string
- join the list with `', '` as separator

UPDATE:

There was another problem: the slots values are retrieved as string (
though the slots were `AMAZON.Number) so they have to be casted to int.

Comment: What kind of error do you have? I've tried with my skill and it works

Comment: I don't know the specific error, I only know that it calls the class `CatchAllExceptionHandler(AbstractExceptionHandler)`

Comment: Cut `results = get_random_values(size,n)` and write `speak_output = "You got " + n + ", " + size` and call the Intent in the same way that give you the error,  in order to see if the problem is in the random generator (don't think so) or somewhere else (maybe in the slots, don't know).

Comment: Without using functions it works. I've tried what you said and it work correctly, that's the strange thing!

Comment: If you put the code of the random generator directly in the handle function before the  `speak_output` assignment?

Comment: I've tried already, it does not work. That's very strange in my opinion!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201854/discussion-between-rivamarco-and-bjorn).

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion of rivamarco, I've checked the logs on Amazon. I found that the problem was that all the values extracted from alexa slots are considered as strings, so I had to perform a cast to `int` in order to use them correctly.